# Simplify formula by removing sum from it

Tags: summation

I have a question about the following formula, I just need to write it without a sum with some formula convertion(simplify it). As for now I'm stuck, I don't know if it is possible for now, but hope it is.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^l \frac{b_i^2}{1+AB_i}, \quad \text{where }B_i=\sum_{\textstyle j= \, i}^L b_{\textstyle j}, \  \text{and } \ l\leq L
$$
I tried to lead to a common denominator, make some assumptions to simplify the formula, but for now I'm stuck, any help is appreciated.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^l \frac{b_i^2}{1+AB_i}= \frac{b_1^2}{1+A(b_1+...+b_L)} + \frac{b_2^2}{1+A(b_2+...+b_L)}+...+\frac{b_l^2}{1+A(b_l+...+b_L)}
$$

Comment: There is a mismatch between how you define $B_i$ and how you show it being used in the expansion. As it's shown, an appropriate matching expression would be $B_i = \sum_{j=i}^{L}b_j$. Is this correct?

Comment: @JohnOmielan, yes it is correct.

Comment: Where did you encounter this sum? What's the context, and why do you think that it's possible that this sum can be written in a closed form?

Comment: @D.R. if you re-read my question you can see that I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2D$ sums in the expression, which can be transformed, using formulas for the negative binomials

$$\frac1{(1-x)^{m+1}} = \sum_{n=m}^\infty \binom nm x^{n-m}$$
which allow to write according polynomial formulas, wherein the polynomial coefficients equal to the binomial coefficients production.

Simplification of the polynomial formulas requires additional assumptions about given coefficients (positive? sorted?$\dots$ Are
$Ab_i < 1?$ etc.)

Partially, if $b_i\in(0,1)$ and $0<A<<1,$ then the approximation
$$1+A\sum b_i\approx \prod(1+Ab_i)$$
allows to obtain suitable common denominators.

Another essential advantages has the approximation 
$$1+A\sum b_i \approx e^{A b_i}.$$

If the sequence $\{b_l\}$ increases and $0<A<<1$ or $L>>l,$ i.e. if $1+AB_l > A(B_1-B_l),$ then looks correct the next approach.

Denote $D_i=1+AB_i,\quad D = D_l,\quad \alpha\,=\dfrac A{D_l},$ then
\begin{align}
&D_{l-1}= 1+AB_{l}+Ab_{l-1} = (1+AB_l)\left(1+\dfrac{A}{1+AB_l}b_{l-1}\right) \approx D e^{\alpha\, b_{l-1}},\\[4pt]
&D_{l-2}\approx D_{l-1} e^{\alpha\,b_{l-2}} = De^{\alpha\,(B_{\,l-2}-B_{\,l})},\dots,\\[4pt]
&D_{i}\approx D_{i+1} e^{\alpha\,b_i} = De^{\alpha\,(B_{\,i}-B_{\,l})},\dots,\\[4pt]
&D_{1}\approx D_{2} e^{\alpha\,b_1} = De^{\alpha\,(B_{\,1}-B_{\,l})},\\[4pt]
&\sum_{i=1}^l\dfrac{b_i^2}{1+AB_i} 
\approx \sum_{i=1}^l\dfrac{b_i^2}{D e^{\alpha\,(B_{\,i}-B_{\,l})}}, 
\end{align}

$$S(\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^l\dfrac{b_i^2}{1+AB_i} \approx \dfrac1{D}\sum_{i=1}^l b_i^2e^{-\alpha S_i},\quad\text{where}\quad S_i=\sum_{j=i}^{l}b_j.$$

Obtained expression looks more suitable for the further detalizations. But I cannot estimate real progress.

On the other hand,

\begin{align}
&D_{l-1}= 1+AB_{l}+Ab_{l-1} = (1+AB_l)\left(1+\dfrac{A}{1+AB_l}b_{l-1}\right),\\[4pt]
&D_{l-2}= 1+AB_{l}+Ab_{l-1}+Ab_{l-1} = D\left(1+\alpha b_{l-2}+\alpha b_{l-1}\right)\approx D\left(1+\alpha b_{l-2}\right)\left(1+\alpha b_{l-1}\right),\dots,\\[4pt]
&D_{i}\approx D\left(1+\alpha b_{i}\right)\left(1+\alpha b_{i+1}\right)\dots\left(1+\alpha b_{l-1}\right),\dots,\\[4pt]
&D_{1}\approx D\left(1+\alpha b_{1}\right)\left(1+\alpha b_{2}\right)\dots\left(1+\alpha b_{l-1}\right),\\[4pt]
\end{align}

$$S(\alpha) \approx \dfrac1{D}\sum_{i=1}^l b_i^2T_i,\quad\text{where}\quad T_l=\dfrac1D,\quad T_i = \dfrac {T_{i+1}}{1+\alpha b_i}.$$

Comment: $0<=b_i <=1$, it is probability, A is just a positive constant.

Comment: @Donvino $A>1$ or less? And what about relations between the probabilities?

Comment: @Donvino Can we say that $\{b_i\}$ increases or decreases?

Comment: @Donvino And why the sums appeared? Sums in the denominators looks such Bayesian ones. If there is approximations, then another form can be used. And the last: which accuracy required?

Comment: $b_i$ increases, A > 0.  Any accuracy that is possible. This formula is a part of bigger formula to find stationary probabilities of queuing system.

Comment: @Donvino First little result. Waiing for comments.